# Mesh At Knee Does Not Bend With IK Rigging

Tags: mesh, rigging

I made a blender IK rig for character that I was modeling. The knee bone bends, but the mesh does not. No matter what type of weight painting I do, the mesh doesn't bend, it just deforms and twists. I also tried rotating the pole target around, but that didn't help.

Here are some screenshots:[image: This is the weight for the lower part of the leg]

[image: Here is what happens when I try to bend the knee]

Comment: Looking at the mesh in the images, looks like you don't have enough geometry to achieve the bending action, do you have an edge loop where the knee is?

Answer (score 1):

The bones can effect only the vertices position, it looks like your leg has only 4+4 vertices. Try subdividing it (in three different ways):

1. Add a subsurf modifier (upper in the modifier stack than the armature modifier)
2. Using the loop ring tool (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
3. Selecting the mesh in edit mode then hitting <kbd>W</kbd>> Subdivide

Search the internet for typical mesh geometry for a good deforming leg and copy the topology.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly. I just added loop cuts at where the knee joints were and now I just need to do some weight painting and it should work. Thank You!

Comment: I've noticed a few of your answers have been edited to include kbd formatting. Kbd formatting helps to indicate a button press and helps it to stand out within sentences. Just something to consider for future answers :)

Comment: Thank you Ray, where can I find infos about how to do kbd formatting?

Comment: @joshsanfelici it's html, kbd stands for keyboard I guess: <kbd>X</kbd> will appear as a keyboard button with the letter X in it