# Leg rig doesn't work

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

I finished the rig of my character and parented it to the mesh. After that I tried to move the leg bone but the leg just stretches (I got an ik bone and a pole target):

[image: leg_rig]

At first I thought its because I didn't weight paint so I went into weight paint mode but everything seems okay.

[[image: weightpaint1]]                      [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyNPD.png)[[image: weightpaint2]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uajRz.png)

I think it has something to do with the ik bone, because the end of the leg always centers to the beginning of the ik bone.
Could someone help me solving this problem?

Comment: Just to be certain, you said you parented the rig to the mesh - you need to parent the mesh to the rig. Or otherwise, give the mesh an armature modifier.

Comment: Also, make sure that the vertex groups are the same names as the bone.

Comment: @Vectorius they have the same names

Comment: @dixiepig gave the mesh an armature modifier but nothing changed at all

Comment: It works! https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53704/48634